# How can i make my body tag span 100% height?

Tags: html, css

For some reason my html body won't span the entire height of the page I'm currently working on.

I'm running out of ideas here. If somebody could take a look at my code it would be really great.

sorry for linking :(

I've already tried applying 100% height and min-height to both html and body tags as most questions here suggest. It didn't solve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't link to an external site : reproduce the problem in a minimal example that you can put here.

Comment: ok i removed the link. However i cant really reproduce the issue because i didnt know how it occured until Satwik helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with the div having the id "content". It has relative position and a large top value assigned to it. To make it simpler, these two properties are causing you the issue :

```
#content {
/*some properties here
position: relative;
top: 199px;
}
```

The body still spans 100% of the height of the page. Its the content div that is being positioned relatively and then 'pushed' 199 pixels below its normal position.

Remove the top property and your body tag will span 100% of the page i.e. Remove this property :

```
top:199px;
```

In essence you CSS class should look like:

```
#content {
    width: 940px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-image: url('images/maincontentbg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

EDIT :

Your CSS file also has this:

```
body {
#content {
    width: 940px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-image: url('images/maincontentbg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    top: 199px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This is plain wrong. If you want to apply CSS to the body and the element having and id "content" then you must write the CSS as such :

```
body, #content {
    width: 940px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-image: url('images/maincontentbg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    top: 199px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

To push it down, you would make of margin instead. Like this:

```
margin: 199px 0px 0px;
```

This will give you the desired effect you were looking for!!

Comment: it is true that it solves my problem but i need the page to be pushed down like it was. how should i achieve this if i cant position it?

Comment: Oh i solved that issue by using margin instead. thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your css.

> html, body{ height:100%; }

Clean your css... and keep study